# How to concat two variables with AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have emails presenting apartment information, including the price in different currencies.

If it's in EUR or CHF then the € symbol appears after the number.
If it's in GBP or USD then the £ symbol appears before the number.

Right now, my AMPscript looks like this, which works for EUR and CHF:

```
%%=FormatNumber(@monthlyprice,"N0",@currencylocale)=%% %%=v(@currency)=%% %%=v(@pmth)=%%
```

But how do I modify it so that it works for GBP and USD as well?

So, in my head it would look something like:

```
IF @CurrencyIsoCode == 'EUR' OR @CurrencyIsoCode == 'CHF' THEN
  SET @price0 = Concat(',FormatNumber(@monthlyprice,"N0",@currencylocale),' ',@currency,')
ELSEIF @CurrencyIsoCode == 'USD' OR @CurrencyIsoCode == 'GBP' THEN
  SET @price0 = Concat(',@currency,' ',FormatNumber(@monthlyprice,"N0",@currencylocale),')
ENDIF
```

This doesn't seem to work but from what I understand, I can't CONCAT variables like this with a FormatNumber function in between.

Can someone please tell me the best way to

Answer (score 2):

@Greg Beazley You can utilize - FormatCurrency function along with Country locale. You can refer this example for FormatCurrency - https://ampscript.guide/formatcurrency/
And for supported locales please refer - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5